# Exchange 2013 Powershell: Setting up Public Folder Mailbox in multi-tenant topography

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013, domain, public-folders

My exchange system has multiple habitats/tenants (i.e. domains).

How do I set my public folder mailbox system?

Do I set one up for each habitat (tenant)? If so, what is the syntax?

Or do I set one public folder mailbox for all habitats?

Comment: Do you really need Public Folders?

Comment: At this stage I don't really know. I have asked the question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/665817/exchange-2013-public-folders-with-contacts-vs-address-book. I just wanted to experiment to see which works best. All I really want is to have a contact list for each of our major customers that all our team members (ie users in our company) can download contact details for.

Comment: @RogerI
Use the source Luke.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150538(v=exchg.150).aspx